# passing a delegate function back to a clr dll which calls a mfc c++ dll in c#

Tags: c#

I have setup a c# console mode program which calls a clr/dll to access a MFC c++ dll and that works for accessing functions in the MFC c++ dll.  But I want to pass back a delegate function from c# so that when a function in the MFC c++ dll needs to call the c# program it has the callback to do that.  But I can't get it setup right...this is my attempt:

program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using dd_clr; // this is my clr.dll


namespace dd_gui
{
    public delegate int GUI_CallbackDelegate(string fn);

    class Program
    {

        int GUI_callback(string fn)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Begin GUI_callback()");
            Console.WriteLine("GUI_callback fn=" + fn);
            Console.WriteLine("End GUI_callback()");
            return (1);
        }

        static GCHandle gch;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    

             Console.WriteLine("begin GUI");

             dd_clr.DDManaged instance = new dd_clr.DDManaged();

             GUI_CallbackDelegate ^ fp = gcnew              GUI_CallbackDelegate(GUI_Callback); // this does not compile for some reason ; expected after gcnew ???
             gch = GCHandle.Alloc(fp);

             instance.Set_GUICallback(fp); // this I am trying to get to work.
             instance.batch_run("test.dap"); // this call works.

             Console.WriteLine("end GUI");

             gch.Free();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code it's not obvious what you are trying to do, but you can pass a delegate to C++ this way:

server.h:

```
extern "C"
{
    typedef int(__stdcall * ComputeCallback)(int);
    __declspec(dllexport) int Sum(ComputeCallback computeCallback);
}
```

server.cpp:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int Sum(ComputeCallback computeCallback)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int x = computeCallback(i);
        sum += x;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

client.cs:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
delegate int ComputeCallback(int value);

class Program
{
    [DllImport("server.dll")]
    public static extern int Sum(ComputeCallback callback); 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ComputeCallback callback = x =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Computing. X = {0}", x);
            return x*x;
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", Sum(callback));
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked, the missing piece was the extern "C" I had tried this previous and would never find my function in the c++ dll.